# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception

Tags: wpf

New to WPF. I want to upload a picture to azure blob when I click a button in my WPF application. I have the following code 1- Open file dialog, 2- GetContainer class. 
Why will this not work?
            private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        // Configure open file dialog box 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Picture"; // Default file name 
        //dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension 
        dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif"; // Filter files by extension 

        // Show open file dialog box 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;//*********************ABOVE CODE OPENS FILES TO SELECT************************
        }

    }
             {
        string uniqueBlobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount objStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*********;AccountKey=************)

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient objclient = objStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer objContainer = objclient.GetContainerReference("rewardsimageblob");

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        objContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "uniqueBlobName"
        CloudBlob blob = objContainer.GetBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);

        // Create or overwrite the "uniqueBlobName" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that we shouldn't provide links as an answer.

But this Windows Azure article covers everything.

[How to use the Windows Azure Blob Storage Service in .NET](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/)

Comment: Thanks I have made an alteration but I get an error "not all paths return a value"

Comment: Your `GetContainer` method doesn't `return` anything. add `return objContainer;` to the end of your method.